# Emailers- When slicing how to avoid shift in slices on emailer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

When we slice an image in Photoshop for an emailer and save out as slices with links how do you avoid a shift in the slices on the emailer once it has sent.

For example; I want to create links to youtube video's on a design with a coloured background. When I do this all the elements shift and create horrible white spaces as well as cut up the text.

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: You need to ensure that there is absolutely no whitespace between the slices in the HTML of the email. But this is probably more for superuser.se (and you will need to specify the email software).

Comment: possibly also webmaster stack exchange

Comment: What is an 'emailer'? Also, this is a code issue. It belongs on StackOverflow rather than Graphic Design.

Answer (score 3):

This is a html email question and has everything to do with how you code the email itself. Post your code on Stack Overflow in the [html-email tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-email).

It is important to note though, that slicing images is really bad practice for html email.  html-email uses a far different 'version' of html to standard web, so anything you pull out of Photoshop will be full of issues in many of the major email clients.

Another thing to note is that emails that are too image heavy incur higher spam scores and you should never send an image only email. Also, all info within an image is unreadable by default, as most email clients do not show images by default.

A well designed html email uses html for all important parts and relies on images only for non critical information.

Comment: While I do think this is off-topic, +1 for the information: email html is a different flavor of html and is not supported totally and uniformly across email reading clients.